# multiple qml files in pyqt

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyqt5

I am using pyqt and I have the following directory structure:

```
root
----> apps/
----> ui/
```

I have a simple qml based application in the app folder as:

**apps/testqt.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView, QQuickWindow
from PyQt5.QtQml import qmlRegisterType, QQmlApplicationEngine
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine('ui/window.qml')
topLevel = engine.rootObjects()[0]
win = QQuickWindow(topLevel)
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

**ui/window.qml**

The qml file defines the app window and uses a StackView as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4


ApplicationWindow {
    id: rootWindow
    objectName: "window"
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 480
    title: "Window"
    Component.onCompleted: {
        setX(Screen.width / 2 - width / 2);
        setY(Screen.height / 2 - height / 2);
    }

    property Component loginView: LoginView {}

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        Component.onCompleted:
        {
            stackView.push(loginView)
        }
    }
}
```

This uses the `LoginView` component which is defined as:

**apps/LoginView.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0


ControlView {
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        spacing: 25
        width: 200

        TextField {
            id: username_fld
            placeholderText: qsTr("User name")
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }

        TextField {
            id: password_fld
            placeholderText: qsTr("Password")
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            echoMode: TextInput.Password
        }

        RowLayout {
            Button {
                id: login_button
                text: "Log In"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }

            Button {
                id: cancel_button
                text: "Cancel"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I use `qmlscene`, the view loads just fine. However, running python results in the application hanging while trying to load the `QQmlApplicationEngine`. I have a feeling it has something to do with the qml paths perhaps, so I included `import ../ui` into the `window.qml` imports but that did not change anything.

I am using `Python 2.7` with `Qt 5.6` in an Anaconda environment. Qt was installed from here: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyqt

Comment: I realized this is not a multiple QML file problem but somehow `PyQt 5.6` is not letting me import `QtQuick.Dialogs`. I have created a follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467572/pyqt-cannot-import-qtquick-dialogs

Comment: One question is: why do you create a second window?

Comment: @KevinKrammer Second window? The dialog import is there cause I wanted to use a FileDialog component at some point.

Comment: the line `win = QQuickWindow(topLevel)` creates a ´QQuickWindow`, the QML already creates a window as its top level. So I am wondering why you create yet another window in Python. Seems like an unnecessary complexity to me.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly i use multiple qml files along with multiple python files. When i access application it loads perfectly two qml files successfully but when stacked through third qml page, the application crashes. It throws segmentation fault.

I use Stackview to push and pop through QML pages, during debugging i found that it works when push and pop are done for just for two pages.

I have came across if i use Swipeview too. What i guess is that the engine that was created can be loaded with two stack QML files.