# Efficient way to switch pyside6 qml screens

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside6

I am working on a project where I have to make a multi-screen/window application. I am using QML and PySide6 for this purpose.
The flow of my applications is like below:

login screen -> search screen (search for certain items) -> test screen (performs some operations) -> reports screen (displays results from test screen).

Currently what I am doing is using a main.py file to load the login page:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys
from api_login_test import get_credentials
# from login_data import get_credentials

from PySide6.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QUrl, QObject
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLineEdit, QPushButton
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    credentials = get_credentials()

    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('credentials', credentials)
    login_file = os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "qml" / "login.qml")
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(login_file)

    def handle_object_created(obj, obj_url):
        if obj is None and url == obj_url:
            QCoreApplication.exit(-1)

    engine.objectCreated.connect(handle_object_created, Qt.QueuedConnection)
    engine.load(url)
    
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

once the login page opens up now for switching rest of the screens, I use javascript function I wrote in all my qml files to switch to next screen. Following is the JS code I am using for switching to next screen.

```
function switch_to_test(access)   {
                if (access == true) {
                    var component = Qt.createComponent("test_interface_dark_debug.qml")
                    var win = component.createObject()
                    win.show()
                    visible = false
                    }
                else {
                    console.log('Invalid Credentials')
                }
                }
```

And this is causing my UI to crash as I reach test screen. So is there a way to efficiently switching the screens without my UI crashing?
I found out [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44518959/19281692) for the crashing of my UI, but I don't know how to resolve the issue.
Thank you

Comment: Why would you create new windows and not just use something like [`StackView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html) or a [`StackLayout`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-layouts-stacklayout.html)?

Comment: Also there is a QML type for [Window](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-window.html#details)

Comment: Didn't think of using StackVIew/StackLayout in that manner. But as per the link I mentioned, it says that they also work upto 2 screens. Can you point me out to any example regarding the same where more than 3 screens are used?

Comment: @ניר I am using ApplicationWindow in place of Window. Will changing it to Window help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a showcase of various approaches regarding to your question.
*Although all the code here is coherent and meant to be run together, It shows different approaches to navigate pages and you may adopt what you like.*

[image]

---

#### Setup:

File *main.py*:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    qml_file = Path(__file__).parent / "main.qml"
    engine.load(qml_file)

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

#### Method 1: Use a [`StackView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html):

File *main.qml*:

```js
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainFrame
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Windows handeling in QML")
    Material.theme: Material.Dark

    StackView{id: stack_view
        initialItem: logginWin
        anchors.fill: parent;
        Component{id: logginWin
            LoginWin{
                onLoggedIn: {
                    stack_view.push(stack_le)
                    console.log("logged In")
                }
            }
        }
        Component{id: stack_le
            StackLayoutWin{
                onReturnToLogginWin:{
                    stack_view.pop()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

File *LoginWin.qml*:

```js
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15

Item{id: root
    anchors.fill: parent;
    signal loggedIn;

    TextArea{id: input_
        placeholderText: "Enter password"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
    Button{
        text: "Login";

        anchors {
            horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter;
            top: input_.bottom
        }
        onClicked: {
            console.log(input_.text)

            if(input_.text == "12345")
            {
                root.loggedIn()
            }
            else{
                input_.text = "Wrong password"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

| Pros | Cons |
| --- | --- |
| Default animation | You will have to `pop` / `append` windows while navigating, That makes it inconvenient for multi-directional pages workflow. |
| Very easy for one direction pages workflow that also can be reversed. | Not very customizable. |

---

#### Method 2 Use [`StackLayout`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-layouts-stacklayout.html) With [`TabBar`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-tabbar.html#details):

Here would be our "main application" window.
You would have here different pages the user would be able to navigate.

File *StackLayoutWin.qml*:

```js
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15

Item{id: root
    signal returnToLogginWin;
    anchors.fill: parent;
    Button{id: return_to_StackView
        x: parent.width - width;
        y: tab_bar.y
        text: "return to login page"
        onClicked: {
            root.returnToLogginWin()
        }
    }
    ColumnLayout{
        anchors.fill: parent;
        TabBar {
            id: tab_bar
            TabButton {
                width: 100
                text: qsTr("foo")
            }
            TabButton {
                width: 100
                text: qsTr("bar")
            }
            TabButton {
                width: 100
                text: qsTr("Loader")
            }
        }


        StackLayout {
            id: stack_layout
            currentIndex: tab_bar.currentIndex
            Rectangle {
                color: 'teal'
                Label{
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: "Page " + stack_layout.currentIndex
                }
                implicitWidth: 200
                implicitHeight: 200
            }
            Rectangle {
                color: 'plum'
                implicitWidth: 300
                implicitHeight: 200
                Label{
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: "Page " + stack_layout.currentIndex
                }
            }
            JustALoader{}
        }

    }
}
```

| Pros | Cons |
| --- | --- |
| Ability to navigate threw different pages simultaneously | Harder to implement than `StackView` |
|  | Not very customizable. |

---

#### Method 3 Use [`Loader`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-loader.html):

File *JustALoader.qml*:

```js
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15

Item{
    anchors.fill: parent;
    ColumnLayout{
        anchors.fill: parent;
        Row{
            Button{
                Layout.fillWidth: true;
                text: " To cyan rect"
                onClicked: {
                    loader_.sourceComponent = cyan_rect
                }
            }
            Button{
                Layout.fillWidth: true;
                text: " To red rect"
                onClicked: {
                    loader_.sourceComponent = red_rect
                }
            }
        }
        Component{id: cyan_rect
            Rectangle{
                color: "cyan"
            }
        }
        Component{id: red_rect
            Rectangle{
                color: "red"
            }
        }
        Loader{id: loader_
            Layout.fillWidth: true;
            Layout.fillHeight: true;
            sourceComponent: red_rect
        }
    }
}
```

| Pros | Cons |
| --- | --- |
| Customizable | Not very useful "out of the box" |

You can find this example [here](https://github.com/nrbnlulu/Qt-answers/tree/master/QtQuick/HandelingWindows)

Note:

- I generally don't use `QtQuick.Controls` because I think it holds you back at a certain point. So I would recommend creating your own page-management when needed using the `Loader` element and other components.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'll try this out today and let you know. Just one quick question, if I have a third screen that I wish to load after processing the second screen so should I create a signal in second screen and add second screen in the main.qml and puch the third screen?

Comment: @lakkadaayush It is a possibility... You can also call Python backed to handle pages.

Comment: I tried your example, It worked fine till second screen, but when I invoked a signal from second screen, in order to switch to third screen, main.qml didn't catch the signal. It got stuck till 2nd screen only.

Comment: There is no third screen here, wym?

Comment: please check the edit.

Comment: @lakkadaayush I would love to help you though it is not related to the original question so you would need to open a new question with an appropriate Header. *Consider removing that edit.*

Comment: Also there are more alternatives I am about to add to my answer.

Comment: Sure, I'll create a new question for this.