# Not able to switch to more than 2 QML files using stackview

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside6

I am trying to switch between multiple screens using stackview in QML. I am following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73012694/19281692). It is working fine till switching from screen 1 to screen 2. But while switching from screen 2 to screen 1, the signal is not getting invoked.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import '../imports/Test'
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainframe
    width: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth
    height: Screen.desktopAvailableHeight
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Dr. T")

    Material.theme: Material.Dark

    StackView {
        id: stack_view
        initialItem: loginWin
        anchors.fill: parent

        Test_interface_dark {
            id: test_screen
            onAnalyzeReport: {
                stack_view.pop()
                stack_view.push('./Report_screen.qml')
            }
        }
        
        Second_screen {
            id: search_screen
            onSearchRegister: {
                console.log('Test signal Invoked')
                // stack_view.pop()
                stack_view.push('./Test_interface_dark.qml')
                stack_view.initialItem = test_screen
            }
        }

        Login_dark {
            id: loginWin
            onLoggedIn: {
                // stack_view.pop()
                console.log(stack_view)
                stack_view.push("./Second_screen.qml")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Login_dark.qml**

```
Item {
    id: login_item
    anchors.fill: parent

    signal loggedIn()

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        color: "#494949"
        anchors.fill: parent
        state: ""
        Button {
            if (condition) {
                login_item.loggedIn()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

similar are Second_screen.qml and Test_interface_dark.qml. But when I try to invoke signal searchRegister from Secondscreen.qml, it does not work, the line `console.log('Test signal Invoked')` in main.qml also does not get printed.

Comment: If you use path for source you don't need to instantiate your items.

Comment: But the signal itself is not recieving to main.qml file. when I try to run the line `console.log('Test signal invoked')` it does not get printed in the console. I also tried to print `console.log(searchRegister)` in my Second_screen.qml, and it gave `undefined`

Comment: Because you used path for your items the callbacks you written are not effective, They are other components

Comment: So what shall I do?

Comment: Wrap them with `Component` and use the id as the source item

Comment: `Component {
    Second_screen {
        id:..
       onSearchRegister: {}
}
}`
this is what you mean?

Comment: Yes, see my answer. I also updated the previous answer you linked. I suggest checking it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to override properties or handling signals within components,
Don't add them with path to the `StackView`.
Instead create components that incubate your other components with the overridden properties inside your `StackView` QML file.
Example:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    width: 500
    height: 500
    title: qsTr("Dr. T");
    visible: true
    Material.theme: Material.Dark

    StackView {
        id: stack_view;
        initialItem: loginWin;
        anchors.fill: parent;


        Component{ id: loginWin;
            LoginDark {
                onLoggedIn: {
                    console.log("to search_screen");
                    stack_view.push(search_screen);
                }
            }
        }


        Component{ id: search_screen;
            SecondScreen {
                onSearch: {
                    console.log("Test signal Invoked")
                    stack_view.push(interface_)
                }
            }
        }

            Component{ id: interface_;
            InterfaceDark {
                onAnalyzeReport: {
                    stack_view.pop()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Full example can be found [here](https://github.com/nrbnlulu/Qt-answers/tree/master/QtQuick/StackView-issue).